# How to group two categories as a one group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group `C,C++,C# and VB,VB.NET` as a different single category with summarized result. Do I need to substitute the team name into a unified value `(e.g. replace C,C++,C# into "C related")` and then do the grouping?

Which one is better in terms of performance? do i need to use Store procedures?
Can someone please advise me how to do it? Thanks!

PS: I am using SQL server

**Original table**

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Team], [Room])
VALUES
    ('Java', 'Room A'),
    ('Java', 'Room B'),
    ('Java', 'Room C'),
    ('Java', 'Room A'),
    ('Java', 'Room C'),
    ('C++', 'Room A'),
    ('C++', 'Room B'),
    ('C++', 'Room C'),
    ('C', 'Room A'),
    ('C', 'Room B'),
    ('C', 'Room C'),
    ('VB', 'Room B'),
    ('VB', 'Room C'),
    ('C#', 'Room A'),
    ('C#', 'Room B'),
    ('C#', 'Room C'),
    ('VB.Net', 'Room A'),
    ('VB.Net', 'Room B'),
    ('VB.Net', 'Room C')
```

**Expected output**

```
('Team', 'Room', 'Count'),
('Java', 'Room A', 2),
('Java', 'Room B', 1),
('Java', 'Room C', 2),
('C related', 'Room A', 3),
('C related', 'Room B', 3),
('C related', 'Room C', 3),
('VB related', 'Room A', 1),
('VB related', 'Room B', 2),
('VB related', 'Room C', 2)
```

Comment: It seems strange to have a row `('Team', 'Room', 'Count')`, do you mean the column name?

Comment: @Eric, I think they're column names. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have another table that maps the language to a language family. That is, Java would map to a value of, say, 1, the C-related to 2, and the VB-related to 3. Then, you can join the two tables and group by the language family. This should perform better than grouping by the strings. If you are interested in improving the performance even more, you could denormalize and add a column to your table for the language family.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `group by` query with a `case` statement:

```
select (case when team in ('C', 'C++', 'C#') then 'C related'
             when team in ('VB', 'VB.NET') then 'VB related'
             else team
        end) as team,
       room, count(*)
from table1
group by (case when team in ('C', 'C++', 'C#') then 'C related'
               when team in ('VB', 'VB.NET') then 'VB related'
               else team
          end), room;
```

Comment: You forgot to add `room` in the `group by` clause.

Comment: For quick solution, I think it is enough for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group in SQL itself, then creating a lookup table first
will be faster in general. The number of records, indexing, and frequency
of usage will all affect response times as well.

First create a lookup table for grouping teams:

```
INSERT INTO Teams ([Team], [TeamGroup])
VALUES
('Java','Java'),
('C++', 'C related'),
('C', 'C related'),
('C#', 'C related'),
('VB', 'VB related'),
('VB.Net', 'VB related')
```

Then run this query:

```
SELECT g.TeamGroup AS Team, t.Room, count(g.TeamGroup) AS Count
FROM Team AS t
INNER JOIN Teams AS g ON t.Team=g.Team
GROUP BY g.TeamGroup, t.Room
```